# Is "a circular pond which is seen oval from in front" right?

Tags: sentence-construction

In a fire temple there is a pond with a special design. Although it is in reality circular but when you look at it from in front when you enter the temple it looks oval.

Now how can I describe this quality proper and easy?
Is "a circular/round pond which is seen oval from in front/side.entrance" right?

[image: Zoroastrian Fire Temple in Yazd. Iran]

Comment: ... a circular pond which **looks** oval ...

Comment: So "There's a circular pond which looks oval when you enter the temple yard" is OK?

Comment: Fersher. Though it hardly seems remarkable: any circle looks oval if not looked at along an axis at its centter perpendicular to its plane.

Comment: You might call this a _reflecting pool_. As for the verb, I like Tamara's suggestion: **the reflecting pool is circular but it _appears_ to be elliptical**.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you a lot for your help:) Though I think It is impressive. The architect has made something which gives you a kind of surprise. I have been there and it was interesting to experience the change you notice as you walk from the yard entrance door towards the entrance of the temple building, specially if you don't know beforehand that the pool is not circular in reality:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most correct way to describe it is "a circular pond which appears oval from the front/side entrance". ("Looks" could also be used in place of "appears".)

"Appears" means to seem or to give the impression of being. The pond seems (or gives the impression of being) oval from the entrances.

"Is seen" implies perception with the eyes. We can use "is seen", but the construction is a little awkward. To use "is seen", we need an adverb ("as") to connect the adjective ("oval") like this: "a circular pond which is seen as oval from the front/side entrance". This is technically correct, but not as clean as "appears" or "looks" (given no other context).

Comment: So is it nice to say "As you enter the temple yard, there's a nice reflecting pool which appears to be elliptical/gives the impression of being oval from where you stand but then when you approach you get kind of surprised since it is circular in reality"?

Comment: Just avoid a run-on sentence. There are two subject/verb pairs ("there's" in the first half, and "you get" in the second half). So we would have something like, `As you enter the temple yard, there's a nice reflecting pool which { appears to be elliptical | gives the impression of being oval } from where you stand. But then when you approach, you get kind of surprised since it is circular in reality.` Note that "elliptical" includes circles (a circle is a special case of an ellipse). So, use "oval" if the pond only appears oval (not circular) from where you stand.

Comment: Great! Thx a lot:)

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about your question for a while now, and I honestly don't believe one would mention the 'oval-ness' of the pool at all.  This is a phenomenon that happens to some extent every time one views a circle from any angle other than from perfectly straight-on.

All that being said, I don't believe anyone would ever actually verbalize this trait explicitly since everyone observes this constantly without remark.

One would likely only ever say: "a circular pool."